# Displaying SQL view with Left Outer Join in MVC3

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using a simple view which is a left outer join on two tables to get the CATEGORY name that each FEE would fall under and group them for display.  When I simply run the view and iterate through the items it repeats the items like it isn't using the same view.

```
    @foreach (var category in Model.FeeScheduleRates())
{
    <tr><td colspan="2">@category.Category</td></tr>
    foreach (var item in Model.FeeScheduleRates())
    {                                  

    <tr> 
        <td>@item.Fee_Title - @item.Description</td>
        <td>@item.Amount</td>                                        
    </tr>
    }                                   
}
```

So I changed my approach to a while loop for the second set of items, but that brought on OUT OF MEMORY errors and doesn't seem to work.

```
@foreach (var category in Model.FeeScheduleRates())
{   
    <tr><td colspan="2">@category.Category</td></tr>
    var cid = category.Cat_ID;                             
    while (category.Cat_ID == cid)
    {
         <tr> 
            <td>@category.Fee_Title - @category.Description</td>
            <td>@category.Amount</td>                                        
        </tr>       
    }                            
}
```

So the questions is, how to iterate through a view and group the items into their categories, displaying the category only once>

I've gone back to the drawing board and using this:

```
                             @foreach (var category in Model.FeeScheduleRates().Distinct())
                            {
                                <tr><td colspan="2">@category.Category</td></tr>
                                foreach (var item in Model.FeeScheduleRates().Where(i=>i.Cat_ID == category.Cat_ID))
                                {                               
                                    <tr> 
                                        <td>@item.Fee_Title - @item.Description</td>
                                        <td>@item.Amount</td>                                        
                                    </tr>
                                }                                   
                            }
```

Have experienced some some form of success in that the categories are appearing as rows and then items beneath.  The funny thing is, it still just repeats the same item as many times as their are records matching that category.  I"m still curious why it isn't iterating through the items properly and giving me each Fee_Title and Description.
Example:

`FREE Services

Bank-to-Bank (B2B) Transfer - funds into FCU    FREE
Bank-to-Bank (B2B) Transfer - funds into FCU    FREE
Bank-to-Bank (B2B) Transfer - funds into FCU    FREE
Bank-to-Bank (B2B) Transfer - funds into FCU    FREE
Bank-to-Bank (B2B) Transfer - funds into FCU    FREE
Bank-to-Bank (B2B) Transfer - funds into FCU    FREE
Bank-to-Bank (B2B) Transfer - funds into FCU    FREE
Bank-to-Bank (B2B) Transfer - funds into FCU    FREE
Bank-to-Bank (B2B) Transfer - funds into FCU    FREE
Bank-to-Bank (B2B) Transfer - funds into FCU    FREE
Bank-to-Bank (B2B) Transfer - funds into FCU    FREE
Bank-to-Bank (B2B) Transfer - funds into FCU    FREE
Bank-to-Bank (B2B) Transfer - funds into FCU    FREE
Savings and Money Market Account
Automatic transfer from Savings -   $2
Automatic transfer from Savings -   $2
Automatic transfer from Savings -   $2
Automatic transfer from Savings -   $2
Automatic transfer from Savings -   $2
Automatic transfer from Savings -   $2
Automatic transfer from Savings -   $2`

So there are 12 items in the DB under the category free and 7 under the Savings and Money Market Account.  It just repeats the first one of each category as many times as there are records in the category.  I do get it!!!

Comment: Why don't you group them int eh SQL

Comment: Maybe that's where I should focus.  The sql bombs out when I try a groupby
`SELECT  a.Cat_ID, a.Fee_Title as title, a.Description, a.Amount, b.Category
FROM     Fee_Schedule AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
         Fee_Categories AS b ON a.Cat_ID = b.Cat_ID
GROUP BY b.Category`

Answer (score 1):

In the `while (category.Cat_ID == cid)` loop neither `category.Cat_ID` or `cid` are changing so the loop will never end.

**Edit**

Looking at the results you're getting you are iterating through distinct categories and displaying the first item against that category multiple times.

You need to iterate through a non distinct list to get all the information and just hide the category name if `lastcategory = thiscategory`.

A good way to work this out would be to write out the pure html for what you want to see **then work backwards to construct it.**

Comment: So maybe I should do a second query for just the categories?  I'd like to use the first Foreach loop to group the categories, but just displaying the view seems to be more complicated than first thought.

OF course using joins in Entity framework wasn't strightforward either.

Comment: You could loop through the all the data sorted by category and pick up category changes to display the category header otherwise blank the cell.

Comment: that's what I thought I was doing with the cid variable.  I've even reassigned the variable in the while loop.

Comment: I'm still not clear on why the item.Category isn't iterating through as we look at the VIEW.  The SQL view:  
   ` SELECT  a.Cat_ID, a.Fee_Title, a.Description, a.Amount, b.Category
FROM     dbo.Fee_Schedule AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN
               dbo.Fee_Categories AS b ON a.Cat_ID = b.Cat_ID
ORDER BY a.Cat_ID`
returns a Cat_ID order listing.  Someone please explain.